Julia: Easiest and efficient way to check if each element of a vector is in another list? .∈ doesn't seem to work
In Julia, assuming I have a vector and a list of candidates:
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
targetlist = [1, 2]

I would like to iteratively check for each element of the vector if it is contained in the target list.
Using \in ∈ works for one element:
x[1] ∈ targetlist
# true

But does not seem to vectorize correctly?
x .∈ targetlist

ERROR: DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 5 and 2


The reason for the error is that you are vectorizing both sides of the operation, but you really only want to vectorize the left side. You must wrap the right side in a container, so it has only a single element. You could do this with Ref (as mentioned in an answer below) or by wrapping in a tuple or a vector, etc. The best solution is Ref or tuple, vector is worse, due to the cost of allocation.

You need to wrap targetlist in a Ref to make it behave like a scalar value:
julia> x .∈ Ref(targetlist)
5-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0

Additionally, if your lists are large, you might want to convert targetlist into a Set to make this operation O(n) instead of O(n^2):
julia> x .∈ Ref(Set(targetlist))
5-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0


Time comparison for 10k Int32 elements in x and y each:
julia> x = rand(Int32, 10000); y = rand(Int32, 10000);

julia> @time x .∈ Ref(y);
  0.118258 seconds (5 allocations: 5.594 KiB)

julia> @time x .∈ Ref(Set(y));
  0.000830 seconds (13 allocations: 86.133 KiB)

